# How to connect to a JDBC database (Filemaker) from the command line (macOS)?

Tags: shell, jdbc

I'd like to connect (and query) a FileMaker database via its jdbc driver `fmjdbc.jar` from the command-line?

How to do this?

I found [`jisql`](https://github.com/stdunbar/jisql) which seems to be a command-line client but as I'm a noob, I don't know how to install / compile it.

Comment: This doesn't sounds like a programming question to me, more like a question to either explain a tool or to ask for suggestions for a tool. Neither is on topic here.

Comment: This would be too narrow even for FileMaker specific forum. On Filemaker community forum there are a few guys who specialise in Java, you should try your question there

Comment: Filemaker is just indicative, the question is more about a jdbc command line client

Answer (score 0):

Rather than compiling `jar` files from source you can download the necessary jars to your computer (or server) and then reference them when calling `jisql`.

The simplest source of prepared jars is the [Maven repository](https://search.maven.org). Search for the library you want and then click "Browse" to get a direct URL for the jar.

Here's an example using Maven to download the jar files. I'm connecting to Redshift here since I couldn't easily find a FileMaker download link.

```
mkdir jisql-test
cd jisql-test
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ranger/jisql/2.1.0/jisql-2.1.0.jar
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/jopt-simple/jopt-simple/5.0.4/jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar
wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-downloads/drivers/jdbc/1.2.37.1061/RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.37.1061.jar

java -cp jisql-2.1.0.jar:jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar:RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.37.1061.jar org.apache.util.sql.Jisql -user my_user -password MyComplexPassword -driver com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver -cstring jdbc:redshift://cluster-name.csds57mn8kff.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/my_db -c \;
```

This should open a query prompt and you are ready to go:

```
Enter a query:
1 > SELECT now();
                                now |
------------------------------------|
      2020-11-19 13:47:10.285999+00 |

Enter a query:
1 >
```